# org-mode tikz drawing behavior abnormal

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-babel

In below example, the text should be show on the right side if compile the latex code with pdflatex command. but in org-mode, the right side text missed:

```
#+HEADER: :fit yes :imagemagick yes :iminoptions -density 300
#+HEADER: :packages '("\\usepackage{tikz} \\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} \\tcbuselibrary{listings}")
#+BEGIN_SRC latex :file sidebyside_20190530.png :results raw file :exports both
\newtcblisting{mybox}{%
    text side listing,
    lefthand width=1.5cm,
    }
\begin{mybox}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, blue] (1,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mybox}
#+END_SRC
```

Current output image is:

[image]

But the actually output should be (if compile from console by pdflatex):

[image]

Code almost the same but org-mode latex will lost the right side text!

Comment: Believe it or not, this appears to be a pdflatex and/or tcolorbox issue, not an Emacs one! From inspecting the Emacs code, org-babel is running the following shell command `pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory /tmp/babel-QnyHjn/ /tmp/babel-QnyHjn/latex-LFrgkY.tex` (with different random letters each time). When I run this exact command locally in the shell (i.e. in the directory of this file), it compiles fine. When I run this command from a different directory in the shell, I get the same output as you. The log gives a missing number error for "l.39 \end{mybox}."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem here is caused by the `listingsutf8` library (as well as a few other things, described below). The `listingsutf8` library is automatically loaded by the `most` option when importing `tcolorbox` with `usepackage`. Removing the `most` option here will prevent `listingsutf8` from being loaded which will allow the source text to show up in the output image.

If you need to use some of the other libraries loaded by most, it's worth noting that `tcolorbox` has a `many` option that loads most of the libraries loaded by `most`. You can import in any additional libraries you need with `\tcbuselibrary`, as you did with the `listings` library.

**Explanation**

The `listings` package requires that the source text it reads is encoded using a single-byte encoding. The `listingsutf8` package was designed to add support for UTF-8 encoded text by parsing the source text into a single-byte encoding. To do this, it first must read the `.listing` file from disk in order to parse it (see [the manual for `listingsutf8`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/oberdiek/listingsutf8.pdf) for more information). This `.listing` file is expected to be in the current working directory. This package is set up to automatically perform this encoding once it is loaded.

TeX is unaware of what directory the input file is located in or if there is an output-directory option that was passed into it. It only knows the name of the file it is compiling, minus its extension. Org Babel calls LaTeX code by making a `.tex` file in a temporary directory, and then calls pdflatex to compile it with the option `output-directory` set to this temporary directory, which causes all output files (including the `.listing` file) to be generated in the temporary directory.
Since the working directory of the org-mode buffer is not this temporary directory and since the `.listing` file is not in the working directory, `listingsutf8` is not able to find the `.listing` file to parse. This is why nothing appears in the right hand side of the output box when compiling your code through Org Babel.

The `listings` package without `listingsutf8` does not need to read the `.listing` file that it generates, which is why not loading `listingutf8` allows this TeX code to compile as expected no matter what the current working directory is.

If the exact same compilation command is run from the temporary directory then the code will compile correctly since `listingsutf8` will be able to find the `.listing` file. Similarly, if the `.listing` file is present in the working directory (e.g. if you moved it there), then the `listingsutf8` will pass that into `listings`. This latter option is a bad idea, however, since this `.listing` file is not generated by the compilation process and is thus not guaranteed to be in sync with the source code.